# Which is the better way of calling function in timeout?

Tags: javascript, node.js

consider this code,

```
var hi = 'Hello';
```

1.First approach

```
setTimeout(function(){
doSomething(hi);
},0);
```

2.Second approach

```
setTimeout(doSomething.bind(null,hi),0);
```

Comment: please define better...

Comment: consider this,
var a = 'hello';

setTimeout(function(){
console.log(a);
},0);

setTimeout(console.log.bind(null,a),0);

which approach is more efficient?

Comment: no I meant define what you mean by the word **"better"**

Comment: I mean both these ways are correct, do you want to know which one has a better performance, ease of comprehension or readability?

Comment: when you say better, please define some output on which our thoughts should be based upon.

Comment: Can you please specify the context in which you want to know which is better ?

Comment: Either works just fine.  There is no better.  If you wanted to find some reason to choose one or the other besides personal opinion, you'd have to specify some sort of criteria for what might make one better than the other such as fewer characters of code, simpler to read, compatible with old browsers, etc... and then compare the two methods based on whatever that criteria is.  Without a specific criteria, neither is "better" than the other.

Comment: There's also option 3: `setTimeout(doSomething, 0, hi)`, assuming you don't need to support IE<=9 (or are happy to polyfill that facility). Note that without seeing the context, it's possible your option 1 won't have the same result because other code might modify the `hi` value before the timeout runs.

Comment: In both the case, your `this` is same (window) and changing `this` is the primary functionality of `bind`. Hence, they both are exactly same, the first one is cleaner though